# Django urlpatterns not catching named route

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have this at the project level:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.urls'))
)
```

and this at the app level:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name = 'home')
)
```

Navigating to http://example.com works just fine and hits the `views.home` function/view, but going to http://example.com/login hits the `views.home` function/view too instead of `views.login` as expected. I know my regex `r'^login/'` matches the `/login` URL pattern -- what have I done wrong here? This is driving me insane because it's dead simple. I have a lot of experience with URL routing/MVC in other languages/frameworks but am sorta new to Django.

One clue is that navigating to http://example.com/login/login (the pattern twice) hits the `views.login` route...

Comment: FWIW the `r'^admin/'` route also works just fine and is almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URLs are very confused. You include the "home" url patterns both for URLs beginning with "login/" and all URLs beginning from the route. So a URL that starts with "login/" will have that prefix chopped off and then start matching in the home url patterns. And of course, when it gets there, it now only contains an empty string, so matches against the empty url pattern.

You should edit the project urls to remove the first "login" pattern altogether, and edit the catch-all pattern to remove the "$" character (you want to match all prefixes, not the empty string).

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('myapp.urls'))
)
```

Comment: Ah, wow. That makes a LOT more sense.. the documentation doesn't really explain it well. For clarification the `home` route is supposed to match `/` (the root) so in the app-level routing it should stay as `r'^$'`?

Comment: You should write the Django routing documentation :) coming from Laravel/CodeIgniter, reading the Django routing docs was pretty awful... it's run-on and doesn't have great examples. (Laravel routing doc here for comparison: http://laravel.com/docs/routing). Thank you!